# Find an equivalent to the function $f(x) = \frac 1 { \sqrt { 1 - x^2 } }$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Find an asymptotically equivalent equivalent to the function $$f(x) = \frac 1 { \sqrt { 1 - x^2 } }$$
around $1$, where for asymptotically equivalent function $f$ of a given function $g$ at a point $a$ I mean a function such that
$$
f\sim_a g\iff \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1
$$ 
I'm searching for that because I saw that $$ x \cdot f(x) = \frac x { \sqrt { 1 - x^2 } }$$ diverges in $1^-$. I don't understand why this should be true, on an analytical level.

Comment: What is an "equivalent to a function"?

Comment: $f $ equivalent to $g$ in $a$ iff$ f \sim_a g$ iff $$ \lim_{x \to a}  \frac{f} {g} (x) = 1$$

Comment: Perhaps you should put that definition in your question and note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 - x)(1+x)}}$.

Comment: The new version still allows utterly trivial answers that presumably you donn;t want, for example $g=f$, or $g(x)=\cos(x)f(x)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is $(-1,1)$.

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+x)(1-x)}}$$

$$\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1-x)}}\;\;\; (x\to 1^-)$$

because $1+x\sim 2 \;\; (x\to 1)$.

Comment: i got confused unnecessarily. you're answer is totally correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

By your definition we want to have $\lim_{x \to 1}  \frac{f(x)} {g(x)} = 1$. Because domain of $f(x)$ is $(-1,1)$, the only possibility is $x \to1^{-}$. Using the L'Hôpital's rule, we get $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}  \frac{f'(x)} {g'(x)} = 1$. So $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}}  \frac{x(1-x^2)^{-3/2}} {g'(x)} = 1$. If $g'(x) = (1-x^2)^{-3/2}$ then we are done. Therefore we calculate $\int(1-x^2)^{-3/2}dx$. By the $x = \sin\theta$ substitution, answer is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} + c$. I think it's possible to obtain other functions in this fashion.

Comment: what is $f$ here ? I'm not sure to understand what you were trying to do.